# Disconnect active SQL connections from SMO

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

Is there a way to use SMO to disconnect all active users from a SQL database, so I can perform a database restore?

The question linked to below is similar, but does not discuss the use of SMO.

[When restoring a backup, how do I disconnect all active connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154200/when-restoring-a-backup-how-to-disconnect-all-active-connections)

This link also is a similar question, but remains unanswered:

http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/smo-detach-fails-due-active-connection-help-122972951.html

Comment: you can always set the `database.useraccess`  property to single user mode...

Comment: Oh nice! I'll give that a try ...

Comment: What was your solution?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the KillAllProcesses method.

`add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
$serverObject = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -argumentList 'YourServerNameHere'
$serverObject.KillAllProcesses('YourDatabaseNameHere')`

If you want to check you can use the GetActiveDBConnectionCount method. But you might want to wait a few second for rollbacks and such
`$serverObject.GetActiveDBConnectionCount('YourDatabaseNameHere')`

Comment: Aha! That's what I was looking for. I tried the `Database.UserAccess` property from the comment on the OP, and that didn't seem to affect anything. Maybe I would have had to wait until all the users disconnected.

Upvoted this answer until I have the chance to test and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect all active users is not a build functionality. You must use the ExecuteNonQuery. I found an example here: http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-windows-powershell/132252-run-transact-sql-using-smo.html

Comment: I think the `Database` class should have a `DisconnectAll()` method or similar. There's no way to do this?

Comment: The problem is if your server is busy and you set the single user mode it's easy that an other process takes control and you can't restore the database. Doing it within a single script prevent this headache. Start with  `ALTER DATABASE databasename SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`. In the same script do your restore and finish with `ALTER DATABASE databasename SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`