# Detach & Restore Database with same Name from .bak Using SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I have an `ASP.NET` web form which have three buttons **Backup**, **Reset** and **Restore** Database.

When i click **BackUp**, it start backup of database and create a .bak file. The **Reset** button truncate all tables. But the **Restore** database will act as Undo i.e when i click **Restore**, it will restore the same database again from .bak file.

Currently, when i click restore it says that the Database is in Use and i cannot restore it. For this, I thought to detach the database first and then restore it with same name from .bak file.

My Idea is to connect to `master` database and from there i will detach my database and then restore it from .bak file. But I am not sure, if it is a good idea or will it work.

I used the following to restore the Database but I want to restore it with same name.

```
    SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + servername + ";Initial Catalog=master;pwd=" + pwd + ";user=" + user + ";"
    SQLcon.Open()
    Try
       SQLCmd = New SqlCommand("Restore database MyDatabaseNew from disk='E:\MyDatabase.bak' WITH MOVE 'MyDatabase_Data' TO 'D:\DATA\MyDatabase .mdf', MOVE 'MyDatabase_Log' TO 'D:\DATA\MyDatabaseLog.ldf',REPLACE,STATS=10", SQLcon)
        SQLCmd.CommandTimeout = CInt(CommandTimeout)
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Response.Write("restore database successfully")
```

How i will achieve this? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Your avoiding the error message. If you have active connections to the database you cannot restore or detach. You have to disconnect all connections to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following in master Database and it worked. I am still not sure whether it is a good approach or not.

```
SET @str = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = ''' + @DBName + ''''    
exec (@Str)     
Print 'Alter Done'    

SET @StrRes = 'Restore database ' + @DBName +' from disk = ''' + @BkPath +''' WITH   MOVE ''MyDB_Data'' TO '''+ @ResPathData +''' ,  MOVE ''MyDB_Log'' TO '''+ @ResPathLog +''' ,  REPLACE,STATS=10 '  

exec (@StrRes)

Print 'Restore Done'
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to run the `master.dbo.sp_detach_db` part at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154200/when-restoring-a-backup-how-do-i-disconnect-all-active-connections

Comment: you mean if i kill the active connections, it will work ?

Comment: `SET SINGLE USER` should remove all connections except yours and solve the the "Database is in Use" error. You shoudn't need to detach as well. Test your script without the `EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = ''' + @DBName + ''''`